# Bash - compare if argument "is one of"

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to test if the first argument is one of: "ABC" or "DEF" or "GHI".

And if it's not - print usage and exit.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/Bash-Beginners-Guide.pdf page 19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^(ABC|DEF|GHI)$ ]]; then
  echo "usage"
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Or `if [[ $1 = @(ABC|DEF|GHI) ]]`, using extended pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

This case runs in sh and bash:

```
case "$1" in
    'ABC' | 'DEF' | 'GHI') ;;
    *) echo "usage"
       exit;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a normal if statement with string comparison:

```
if [ "$1" != "ABC" -a "$1" != "DEF" -a "$1" != "GHI" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 ABC|DEF|GHI"
    exit 0
fi
```

Or:

```
if [ "$1" = "ABC" -o "$1" = "DEF" -o "$1" = "GHI" ]; then
    # Do something.
else
    echo "Usage: $0 ABC|DEF|GHI"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Don't use `-a` and `-o`; they are all but deprecated. Either use separate `[` commands joined by `&&`/`||` or use `[[...]]` in `bash`, which allows `&&` and `||`.